# How to Dynamic UITextView height with contains increses as well as subview dynamic with textview height and move button in ios

Tags: ios7

[image]

i m using this code but text view going outside from subview

```
CGRect frame = self.dealDetailTextView.frame;
frame.size.height = self.dealDetailTextView.contentSize.height;
self.dealDetailTextView.frame = frame;

CGRect moreViewFrame =  self.popUpView.frame;
moreViewFrame.size.height = frame.size.height + 150;
self.popUpView.frame = moreViewFrame;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);

    //Set new frame size and also change popUpView frame base on newFrame
    textView.frame = newFrame;

}
```

Comment: thanks for response ....this code is working only for textview expand with content size its right but i want view also expand and button height will same from buttom .

Comment: Right down code when change textview frame height then you change view height and change button Y position.

Comment: please help me i cant get it because i m new here .

Comment: You know how to change view frame ?

Comment: i knw but don't knw what i use here

Comment: but i want dynamic view

Comment: can you tell me what is your textview height ?

Comment: text is coming from api in textview so it is not fixed it expand acording to contain

Comment: I know but what is static size ?

Comment: and view size is 299 x 222

Comment: and in view i m taking button and label